# Verilog Code for specific kind of counter (Problems)

Tags: memory, verilog

Good afternoon people, i'm trying to code in Verilog a structure than can store up to 64 different 8bit numbers (64X8), which is only allowed to store numbers greater than 125 and bellow or equal to 250. When it is writing (or not), it can show the maximum current stored value (VAL_MAX) as well as it's position (POS_MAX). When not writing (EN_WR ==0) i simply put in POS_RD the position that i want, in order to see what number is stored there, and when the memory is full (NR_ST = 64) it replaces  the oldest stored numbers with the new ones, one by one. I currently have the code but there are some issues:

1st - When the memory is full and for eg. i have 250 in the 2nd position, the output will be 
VAL_MAX= 250 ;  POS_MAX=1. When a bunch of new numbers come, that maximum should be replaced with the 2nd highest stored value and must show it's position, but the memory isn't showing a new Max Value.

2nd - When i want to see the number stored in the 1st position (POS_RD = 0) the output VAL_RD (used to read the stored numbers) is "X" and not the stored number, i don't know if it is saving or not.

The code is:

```
module Bloco(VAL_SENSOR, EN_WR, POS_RD, NR_ST, VAL_MAX, POS_MAX, VAL_RD, segundo, clk);

parameter MEM_SIZE = 64;
parameter MEM_WIDTH = 8;
parameter ADDR_SIZE = 5;

input[MEM_WIDTH - 1:0] VAL_SENSOR;
input[5:0] POS_RD;
input EN_WR,segundo,clk; 

output[6:0] NR_ST;  
output[MEM_WIDTH - 1:0] VAL_MAX; 
output[ADDR_SIZE    :0]POS_MAX; 
output[MEM_WIDTH - 1:0]VAL_RD;

reg[MEM_WIDTH - 1:0] ram[MEM_SIZE - 1:0]; // C , L
reg[MEM_WIDTH - 1:0] VAL_RD;

reg[MEM_WIDTH - 1:0] val_max = 0;       //necessita de variavel so por causa do valor inicial
reg[ADDR_SIZE    :0] POS_MAX = 0;
reg[ADDR_SIZE    :0] POS_MAX2 = 0;
reg[ADDR_SIZE + 1:0] NR_ST_COUNTER = 0; //addr_size + 1 because it needs to count from zero to the number of values
reg[ADDR_SIZE    :0] POS_POINTER = 0;

assign VAL_MAX = val_max;
assign NR_ST = NR_ST_COUNTER;

always @ (posedge clk) 
begin
    if(EN_WR) //Caso esteja habilitado o sistema de armazenamento
    begin
        if(segundo)
        begin
            if(VAL_SENSOR > 125 && VAL_SENSOR <= 250) //Se for um numero abaixo de 250 unid. luminosas e acima de 125
            begin   //Escrita
                if(POS_POINTER == POS_MAX)
                    POS_MAX <= POS_MAX2;
                else
                    ram[POS_POINTER] <= VAL_SENSOR;

                if(NR_ST_COUNTER < 64)      //atualizar Contador de Valores guardados
                    NR_ST_COUNTER = NR_ST_COUNTER + 1;

                if(VAL_SENSOR > val_max)    //atualizar MAX
                begin
                    POS_MAX <= POS_POINTER;
                    val_max <= VAL_SENSOR;
                end
                else                        //ver se encaixa no segundo maior POS_MAX2
                begin
                    if(VAL_SENSOR > ram[POS_MAX2])      //nao precisa guardar o valor

                        POS_MAX2 <= POS_POINTER;

                end
                POS_POINTER <= POS_POINTER + 1;
            end
        end
    end
    else
        VAL_RD <= ram[POS_RD];
    end

endmodule
```

.

NOTE = The input "segundo" is like EN_WR, but it's only used after 10 clock cycles (it will be linked to a Counter).
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you have this line `assign VAL_MAX = val_max;` ? why not just declare `output reg [MEM_WIDTH - 1:0] VAL_MAX;`

Comment: "that maximum should be replaced with the 2nd highest stored value". 250 is the maximum value you can store but if you already have 250 stored you expect it to store the second highest number? At what point do we invalidate the max value?

Comment: Is it intentional that you only read when not writing.

Comment: If 250 is replaced, the second highest number stored (imagine if it is 240 ) should be shown as well as it's position

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1) The reason you are likely not seeing the second highest value in your memory appear on `VAL_MAX` when the current max is overridden is because you never change `val_max` register to contain the value of `ram[POS_MAX2]`, ie the second highest value. However, as you do not have an ordered data structure and do not store any more than the second highest value (and do not search the memory for the second highest value), you cannot reliably keep finding the next highest value when the current highest is removed/overridden. You might need to rethink alot of how you are doing this if you need to always have the current highest value in the memory being output on `VAL_MAX`.

2) Position 0 is not being written to the first time you write to the memory; thus you are getting the default value of the memory, ie `'x`. Here way:

```
if(POS_POINTER == POS_MAX)
  POS_MAX <= POS_MAX2;
else
  ram[POS_POINTER] <= VAL_SENSOR;
```

In the above lines, you only put values in the memory if the current position is not equal to the position of the current highest value. The first time you write (ie, to position 0), `POS_POINTER` and `POS_MAX` are at their initial values of 0, thus equal. So, `ram[0]` never gets updated as it is only executed if `POS_POINTER` and `POS_MAX` are not equal (which in this case, they are equal). If you were to write to position 0 a second time, you might be able to write to it as the value of `POS_MAX` might have changed. Note also, that you sometimes update the write pointer `POS_POINTER` even if you dont write there, as in the example above (even through `ram[0]` wasnt written to, you will still update `POS_PONTER` to be 1).

As mentioned in #1, depending on your requirements, you might not have the right structures here to meet them. If you always need to have the highest value in the memory output on `VAL_MAX` and always have the old value ejected, you might need to make old of those operations do a search, or store and update all the needed meta data.

Comment: So, my code structure is wrong, what could be the nearest possible code to do the task that i planned?

Comment: @MatheusMra Thats a big question which depends on your timing and area constraints. Possible solutions are quite varied, but Im not sure if there is a way in 1 cycle with minimal area. (Ie, if you want to do a write in a single cycle, the logic would get quite large)